# Using SQLiteOpenHelper from separate processes

Tags: android, sqlite, process, sqliteopenhelper

I have an intentservice which is triggered by alarmmanager about every hour it download data from a server and doing insertions on one of my sqlite database table.

I have another long running background service which catches SCREEN_ON actions and also doing insertions and readings on the same database table. The background service run in its own process. This is how I declare it in the manifest:

```
 <service
    android:name=".MyBackgroundService"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="false"
    android:process=":background"/>
```

My question is what if by coincidence two services doing database insertions/readings on exact same time, will it cause any problems like crashing my app? If so. How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, having multiple processes write to the same database at the same time will cause issues which will likely result in your app crashing (remember a database is actually a file on internal storage).

A [ContentProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html) is a high level component you register in your manifest that allows multiple processes (or other apps if you use `android:exported="true"`) to read and write data and uses a Cursor based API that fits naturally with a SQL-based database.

The [Creating a Content Provider training](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html) goes through the steps required in building a Content Provider including building a Uri scheme (a way of uniquely determining what table/row you are talking about) - generally you'd be able to replace your direct accesses to your database with the equivalents to [ContentResolver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html).

Comment: Does this guarantee my sqlite transactions will be queued up and finish if collisions encountered?

Comment: Yep, you'd only have one `SQLiteOpenHelper` that everything would go through across your whole app.

Comment: "having multiple processes write to the same database at the same time will cause issues which will likely result in your app crashing" -- SQLite handles this on other platforms. I agree that a `ContentProvider` is the right answer here, but I am curious if you know something about SQLite on Android that would prohibit multi-process access.